# Virtualizing raspberry pi (as guest) on bochs?

Tags: operating-systems, games, virtualization

Is it possible to run raspberry pi as a VM on Bochs (the hypervisor)?

Actually I've an R Pi application which I would like it to run on a PSP game console, also I've found that the bochs hypervisor is supported on PSP:

http://www.hacker.co.il/psp/bochs/

The application is super light weight and needs like 80k of memory ([tic-80](https://tic.computer)).

So in other words can everything be stacked in this way?:

> Tic-80 -> raspberry pi -> Bochs -> PSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this does not work. Bochs emulates IA-32 alias x86 architecture. It is NOT a hypervisor. Raspberry Pi is running on ARM Cortex A series (or ARM 11 in case of the original Pi and Pi Zero).
You will need to find another way to get Tic-80 on your PSP.
Either an emulator for ARM architecture or a direct port of Tic-80 to MIPS.

Comment: "emulates ia32" and it's not a hypervisor, so does it work in a way similar to dosbox? Or like a Java VM reading .class byte codes?

Comment: DOSBox consists of not only emulating the hardware (as Bochs does) but also providing as DOS compatible OS emulation on top (which you will have to provide separately in Bochs). But yes, the underlaying principles are the same.